# Compactness of a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I tried to solve this exercise taken from the text *Manetti - Topologia*, pg. 81.

> Let's consider the metric space $(\mathbb{Q},d_e)$, with $d_e$ the standard euclidian distance.
>
> Show that $K=${$x \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 \leq x \leq \sqrt2$} is closed, bounded, but not compact.

---

It's a bounded set because $sup_{x,y \in K}$ $d_e(x,y)=\sqrt2$.
It's closed because the complementar set is $C_\mathbb{Q}(K)=(-\infty,0) \cup (\sqrt2,+\infty)$, which is an open set since for every $x$ there is an open set $B$: $x \in B_\epsilon(x)=$ {$y \in \mathbb{Q}: |x-y| <\epsilon$} $\subset A$.

I think it's not compact because if I have an open set $U_\alpha$ which covers $\sqrt2$, then there's an open ball $B_(\sqrt2)$ and so there's a $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x=\sqrt2$, which is a contradiction.

Is it right?

Comment: K is not complet, then it is not compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. That would simply mean there are no (rational) open sets around $\sqrt{2}$, which is absurd.

One way to argue would be to say that, in a metric space, compactness implies sequential compactness, i.e. all sequences in the set have a convergent subsequence. Now, in the set, there clearly is an increasing sequence $(a_n)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sqrt{2}$ (in the sense of working over the real numbers). Then no subsequence of $(a_n)$ has a rational limit, and as such the set is not sequentially compact.